# Can't enable bluetooth because of adapter

Tags: bluetooth

I can't use my Bluetooth with Ubuntu 12.04 64bit .

I have installed `bluetooth`, `gnome-bluetooth` and `blueman` packages. But i'm getting **No adapter found** error.

```
eray@eray-vaio-ubuntu:~$ sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
[sudo] password for eray: 
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
eray@eray-vaio-ubuntu:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
eray@eray-vaio-ubuntu:~$ sudo hciconfig sony-bluetooth reset
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
eray@eray-vaio-ubuntu:~$
```

I'm remambering, i was able to use my bluetooth with Ubuntu, about 7-8 months ago. So Ubuntu supporting my bluetooth device.

How can i install my bluetooth and solve this problem ?

**NOTE** , I've read a lots of question about this. Generally there are 3 answers.

1. Upgrade to 12.04
2. execute `sudo hciconfig hci0 reset` command
3. unblock your device if it's blocked.

But as you seen, none of them helped me. Because of this, i'm asking this question.*It's not a duplicated question*.

**Additional Datas**

1. These are `dmesg` messages about Bluetooth : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1324079/
2. This is exact result of `lsusb -v` : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1324100/ (**I got `Couldn't open device, some information will be missing` error 9 times !**)
3. I have `linux-firmware` but not `linux-firmware-nonfree`

Comment: ok - I'm going to refund your bounty.  This is a confirmed bug here (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/898826) - you'll note, there is a workaround in #31 (I'm not sure if this is quantal or precise fix) - please subscribe to the bug report for updates.

Comment: @fossfreedom , ok last question. At first step : `1) download the ubuntu's linux-source` . But which linux-source should i download ? http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-source

Comment: yep - that looks reasonable - `apt-get source linux-source` at a guess. If in doubt, post the in the bug thread for further help and clarification.